# Let $X_{1},X_{2}, \dots, \sim Exp(1)$ i.i.d. - Calculate the probability of $P[\max{(X_{1},\dots,X_{n},)} < \log(n) - 5] $ for $ n > e^{5}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1},X_{2}, \dots, \sim Exp(1)$  i.i.d.  - Calculate the probability of $P[\max{(X_{1},\dots,X_{n},)} < \log(n)-5] $ for $ n > e^{5}$ as well as $n \rightarrow \infty $

The correct solution is: $(1 - e^{-(\log n-5)})^{n} = (1 - \frac{e^5}{5})^{n} \rightarrow e^{-e^{5}}$

My solution would be only $(1 - e^{-\lambda \ln({n-5})})$  according to the density function
$F(x)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^x f_\lambda\left(t\right)\ {\rm d}t = 
\begin{cases}
  1-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x}& x\geq 0, \\ 
  0                        & x < 0. 
\end{cases}$

How do I get the stated term?

Comment: Iff X,Y are iid with CDF $F$ then $P(\max(X,Y)<z) = P(X<z)P(Y<z) = [F(z)]^2$.

Comment: I don't think the given solution is correct.  @Jack-Daurizio's answer correctly calculates $e^{-\ln(n-5)}$ as $\frac{1}{n-5}$. Are you sure that $\log(n)-5$, which is positive when $n > e^5$ was not intended? With this change, we have $$\left(1 - e^{-(\ln(n)-5)}\right)^{n} = \left(1 - \frac{e^5}{n}\right)^{n} \rightarrow e^{-e^{5}}$$ which seems to make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, the probability that $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is less than $k$ is just the probability that $X_i\leq k$ holds for any $i\in[1,n]$, hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}[\max_i X_i\leq\log(n)-5]&=&\left(\mathbb{P}[X_1\leq\log(n)-5]\right)^n=\left(\int_{0}^{\log(n)-5}e^{-x}\,dx\right)^n\\&=&\left(1-\frac{e^5}{n}\right)^n\approx e^{-e^5}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I think that the problem statement has a typo, and that $\ln(n)-5$, which is positive when $n > e^5$ was intended; not $\ln(n-5)$ for which the constraint $n > e^5$ seems useless.

Answer (score 1):

The event $E = \{\max(X_1, .., X_n) < \ln(-5)\}$ is equal to the intersection of the events $E_i = \{ X_i < \ln(-5)\}$; i.e., $$ E = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n E_i.$$ By independence then $$ P(E) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n P(E_i)$$ and $P(E_i)$ seems to be what you're calculating...